# kibana filter for timestamp-range with conditions

Tags: kibana

I collect some simple data entries which are summed up and the sum is shown as a number on a kibana dashboard. I monitor this number to see if it's too high in a specific timespan.

Unfortunately the regarding timespan is from 1:30pm to 1:30pm, so I have two cases:

1. If it's e.g. 11am: I want to see the sum from yesterday 1:30pm till now
2. If it's e.g. 3pm: I want to see the sum from today 1:30pm till now

For both cases I can create a filter but have to change it depending on the current time. Is it possible to somehow combine the filter to get the correct data? Some kind of condition if now is before or after a specific time or so.?

Filter 1:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "lt": "now",
        "gte": "now-1d/d+750m"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Filter 2:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "lt": "now",
        "gte": "now/d+750m"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

regards
Oliver